# In ASP.NET Core 2.1, using identity with external login providers, should ExternalLogin method be POST only?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

In most examples I can find, the prototypical Account/ExternalLogin endpoint from most of the samples is implemented as a POST method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
```

In my error logs, I'm seeing a decent number of 404's being returned due to a GET request:

```
GET /Account/ExternalLogin
```

Is this the result of some sort of bot that I can safely ignore, or should the endpoint accept any method (or at least GET and POST)?

Comment: Why are those GET requests made in the first place? I doubt users of your API make so many bad calls and dont' care about the results. Did you check the web server's logs? Do you recognize the IPs that made those calls?

Comment: There are no users of my API.  This is an interactive external login for a user that clicked Login With and Google, Facebook, or Microsoft.  In other words, they just clicked a logo, entered their user/password for the external provider, and are expecting to get back to my site logged in.  I've figured it out though.  It must be bots.  That endpoint is part of a POST form on my own site... I was thinking it was part of the redirects that happen.  The only way it can be GET is if some bot is probing.  I will continue to ignore GET requests as there is no legitimate reason to support them.

Comment: Did you check the web server logs? No need to guess, check the IPs

Comment: Digging deeper I've identified the requests as coming from SemrushBot.  I'm not sure why it's doing a GET request on an action from a form marked with POST, but at least I know the source now.

Comment: Bots don't know anything about your code, they just try the URLs they find in the HTML or try various well-known URLs. You should add a robots.txt to your site or outright block misbehaving IPs. You are paying for those GETs after all

Comment: You can block specific routes using middleware and filters as the [IP Safelist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/ip-safelist?view=aspnetcore-2.1) article in the docs shows

Comment: Thanks.  I've added the /account/ branch to robots.txt.  Still think it's odd a bot wouldn't know a link from a form...

Comment: Bots aren't *that* smart and HTML parsing isn't easy either. You need that `robots.txt` anyway to avoid wasting money on such bots. On a cloud environment the combined CPU, bandwidth costs can be significant over time

Comment: I'd also suggest looking for Troy Hunt's article where he explains how he handled such issues for Have I Been Pwned. He pays for the site out of his pocket so he really hates paying for bots. For its popularity, the site runs on a *very* small instance

Answer (score 0):

I am considering this resolved.  I was too deep into the logs and forgot that the endpoint in question is the first part of the external login process and is user-initiated from the login form itself.  Therefore, it can only legitimately be a POST.  Any GET request is almost certainly a bot trying to probe the site.